# Execute symbolicatecrash from shell script

Tags: ios, shell, sh, symbolicatecrash

I am trying to call symboliccrash from a shell script that loops through multiple crash log file and outputs symbolicated version, but it is failing with an error message saying "command not found"

But it works fine in the command line.

```
symboliccrash CRASH_FILE.crash APP.dSYM > symbolicated.crash
```

I tried to find the source for symboliccrash but it fails to find it

```
which -a symboliccrash
```

Shell Script Code

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
export DEVELOPER_DIR="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer"
i=0

for x in *.crash;
do
        symboliccrash $x MyApp.dSYM > $i.crash
        i=$((i+1))
done
```

Response

```
compareUUD.sh: line 7: symboliccrash: command not found
```

Any idea how i can do this.

Comment: can you post your shell script code?

Comment: @ReinierMelian Add shell script above, hope that helps

Comment: OK I will review and i tell you any results

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think that you need first of all is execute this command

```
find /Applications/Xcode.app -name symbolicatecrash -type f
```

on your Terminal, this will retrieve the localization of your `symbolicatecrash` something like this

> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DVTFoundation.framework/Versions/A/Resources/symbolicatecrash

then you need to update your script to this code

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
export DEVELOPER_DIR="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer"

alias symbolicatecrash='/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DVTFoundation.framework/Versions/A/Resources/symbolicatecrash'

i=0

for x in *.crash;
do
        symbolicatecrash $x MyApp.dSYM > $i.crash
        i=$((i+1))
done
```

and replace the direction of `symbolicatecrash` for the result given by the execution of `find /Applications/Xcode.app -name symbolicatecrash -type f`

and that is it,execute with `sudo sh`, I tested and result in this error

> No crash report version in 0.crash at
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DVTFoundation.framework/Versions/A/Resources/symbolicatecrash
>   line 1007.

But I asume that this error is because I don't have any crash or dSYM so I think that now is working, I hope this help you

Comment: It works. Thank you so much for that find call, i was trying "which" instead

Comment: Aliases aren't expanded by default in a non-interactive shell, even if you define one in the shell. Better to just add the required directory to the `PATH`.